# How to extend TypeScript knowledge of the new inheritances?

Tags: typescript

How to make TypeScript to be aware of all inheritances that happened in `Base` variable of `Factory` class, so I can get no errors. It should definitely be possible because I get the result at the end, but `Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Rect'` errors are thrown.

```js
interface IPrintable {
    print(): void;
}

interface ILoggable {
    log(): void;
}

class Factory<T extends new (...args: any) => IShape> {
    constructor(public Base: T) {}

    Printable() {
        this.Base = class extends this.Base implements IPrintable {
            print() {
                console.log(`${this.x}:${this.y}`);
            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    Loggable() {
        this.Base = class extends this.Base implements ILoggable {
            log() {
                console.log(`${this.x}:${this.y}`);
            }
        }

        return this;
    }
}

interface IShape {
    x: number,
    y: number
}

class Rect implements IShape {
    constructor(
        public x: number,
        public y: number
    ) {}
}

const RectMaxed = new Factory(Rect).Printable().Loggable().Base;
const rectMaxed = new RectMaxed(10, 20);
rectMaxed.print();
rectMaxed.log();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a new instance of the factory every time when adding a method. Try out this code:

```
interface IPrintable {
    print(): void;
}

interface ILoggable {
    log(): void;
}

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class Factory<T extends new (...args: any) => IShape> {
    constructor(public Base: T) {}

    Printable() {
        return new Factory<T & Constructor<IPrintable>>(class extends this.Base implements IPrintable {
            print() {
                console.log(`${this.x}:${this.y}`);
            }
        });
    }

    Loggable() {
        return new Factory<T & Constructor<ILoggable>>(class extends this.Base implements ILoggable {
            log() {
                console.log(`${this.x}:${this.y}`);
            }
        });
    }
}

interface IShape {
    x: number,
    y: number
}

class Rect implements IShape {
    constructor(
        public x: number,
        public y: number
    ) {}
}

const RectMaxed = new Factory(Rect).Printable().Loggable().Base;
const rectMaxed = new RectMaxed(10, 20);
rectMaxed.print();
rectMaxed.log();
```

I added a new type `Constructor<T>` which indicates a class. You can also try it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUqjHARgGxQG8AoZc5ABy3AAoBKALmQDcB7YAEwG4SBfEiWzR4SNABk2Acyl5CyUhWT5pDZuy68BYAJ6UUAYTYgAzmCgBXBGDZQAPABUAfMgC8yEBADuyWgDoAuCgpE2Y4EB0AbQBdejcXB14SBHw4ExNkADFEGygdR2QIAA9IEE4Mzx9-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-QDv04PxqGwBheAQoCjz9SkeSAA).